# How to compare, then update in AJAX if necessary

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list containing news articles in the backend of a site which is then displayed on a homepage. I'd like the homepage to always display the most recent news.

I've never used AJAX before but in pseudo it would need to do the following:

- call the homepage using an AJAX-get
- Compare the article div with the same div from the AJAX-get.
- If the AJAX-get has different content inside the div, display that

Can I do this with Jquery load, or do I need to go into AJAX for this functionality. and if so, could anyone give me a hand with the AJAX itself

trying to use AJAX, i have started using the following code, to no avail

```
$.ajax({
    url: ctx.HttpRoot,
    data: { "id": $("newsSliderWrapper").attr("id") },
    success: function (data) {
        data = $(data).find('div#newsSliderWrapper')
        alert(data)
    },
    error: function () {
        // your error logic
        alert("AJAX failed");
    }
})
```

Comment: What differences between the two elements would you be looking for? You would need to use `$.ajax` for this due to the extra control it allows you.

Comment: the list currently displays all items in a list by date, then hides them all and uses jquery fades etc to display one at a time. so id probably compare the first child of a wrapper div and see if they are different

Answer (score 0):

AJAX in your case will do the following:

1. Ajax call will send the recent article ID to the server.
2. The server will compare the article ID. If the article ID is different, then the server will return the new article content. If the id is same, return different status message.
3. Ajax call will simply render the content

So

```
$.ajax({
   url : "backendurl",
   data : {"id" : $("recentarticleDivId").attr("id")}, 
   // id must be the article ID which you need to match
   success :  function(data) {
      $("#articleDivId").html(data);
   },
   error : function() {
      // your error logic
   }
})
```

Comment: that doesnt seem to work really, I cant use the responsetext or anything like that, i've used your idea and then come out with the following code (ill put it in the OP):

Comment: Your responsetext is the data which the success function holds. Assuming you are passing the JSON/XML from the backend, you need to iterate the object and construct the article div and replace the older one. In case you are passing the HTML string itself. Just put that data inside the div

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "homepage.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: { id : article_id },
    success:function(data){
       console.log(data);
       // your logic
    },
    error:function(){

   }
});
```

Comment: still nothing. Im also not trying to write to the server, simply ='GET'